# hide and show columns- kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angular-kendo

How to hide and show columns of kendo grid without using jquery?
here is the js fiddle link for the example: http://jsfiddle.net/tmLmk/7/

HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="GridController">    
    <div kendo-grid k-options="options" k-data-source="sData"></div>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
angular.module('angular-kendo-example', ['kendo.directives']);

function GridController($scope) {
    $scope.options = {
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [{
            field: "column1",
            title: "column 1",
            width: "40px"
        },{
            field: "column2",
            title: "column 2",
            width: "70px"
        },{
            field: "column3",
            title: "column 3",
            width: "70px"
        },{
            field: "column4",
            title: "column 4",
            width: "60px"
        },{
            field: "column5",
            title: "column 5",
            width: "40px"
        },{
            field: "column6",
            title: "column 6",
            width: "40px"
        }],

    };
    $scope.sData= [
        { column1: "column1 data", column2: "column2 data", column3: "column3 data", column4:  "column4 data",  column5: "column5 data", column6: "column6 data"  }, { column1: "column1 data", column2: "column2 data", column3: "column3 data", column4:  "column4 data",  column5: "column5 data", column6: "column6 data"  }, { column1: "column1 data", column2: "column2 data", column3: "column3 data", column4:  "column4 data",  column5: "column5 data", column6: "column6 data"  }
    ];
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add

columnMenu = true,

Before the columns declaration this should give you the column menu which should enable the show and hide columns options.

This link should help

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/column-menu

Comment: thanks for the answer. it worked. But disabling the columns is resizing other columns haphazardly. How to solve this?

Comment: The resizing will be due to the other columns taking up the available space left by the column being hidden. I'm not sure there is much you can do about this without setting new widths on all columns once you hide one.

Comment: Yes, but in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/tmLmk/14/    , the columns look collapsed as soon as i hide 1 column. how can this be prevented?

Comment: Taking the widths from the columns allows them to auto grow and use the available space. http://jsfiddle.net/4q35k/ with my change. maybe applying a css min-width class to the columns will resolve the collapsing looking.

Answer (score 0):

Given the name of your *Kendo UI Grid in AngularJS*, in your case **`$scope.options`**

you can hide each column programmatically passing the column index, like that:

```
$scope.options.columns[3].hidden = true;
```